# The changes I make to an external JS file of my WP plugin are only applied after I clear my browser's cache

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

I'm making a WordPress plugin which loads an external JS file for some Google Maps related operations. But the problem is that the changes I make to this external JS file are not applied immediately and shown on the Google Chrome browser, but instead I have to delete the "Images and other data" cache of Chrome in order for the changes I make to the JS file to be applied.

For example I have an `alert("DynamicMap.js file was loaded succesfully.);` in the first line of the file but the changes I make to the text only apply after I clear the cache. Does anyone know why does this happen and if I can prevent it? Thanks in advance. (Note that I'm testing plugin online on my personal website, not on the localhost.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function `filemtime($path)`, where `$path` is a path to your script, in `wp_enqueue_script` call, as fourth parameter (version). Every time you modify the script, the cache will be bypassed.

#### Update

Calls to `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script`:

```
wp_register_script('DynamicMapScript', plugins_url('DynamicMap.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), filemtime(dirname(__FILE__) . '/DynamicMap.js'));
wp_enqueue_script('DynamicMapScript');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. I called the function `filemtime($path)` both in my `wp_register_script` call and `wp_enqueue_script` call like this: `wp_register_script( 'DynamicMapScript', plugins_url('DynamicMap.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), filemtime( plugins_url('DynamicMap.js', __FILE__) ) );` and `wp_enqueue_script('DynamicMapScript', '', array(), filemtime( plugins_url('DynamicMap.js', __FILE__) ) );`. The cache is still not bypassed.

Comment: Where, within your plugin folder, `DynamicMap.js` script is located?

Comment: It's located in the root folder of my plugin. No sub-folders.

Comment: `filemtime` function expects a path to the file, not URL Replace `filemtime(plugins_url('DynamicMap.js', __FILE__))` with `filemtime(dirname(__FILE__) . '/DynamicMap.js')`, in your code.

Comment: What do i put in `dirname`? The full path to my plugin under the base url of my site eg `wp-content/plugins/Map_of_resellers` or only the subfolder of my plugin under the `plugins` folder eg `Map_of_resellers`?

Comment: Just `__FILE__`. It will return full path to your plugin folder with no trailing slash. **Note:** you can call `wp_engueue_script` with just a handle: `wp_engueue_script('DynamicMapScript');`

Comment: Typo: `wp_engueue_script` should be `wp_enqueue_script`. Sorry.

Comment: Perfect, your solution worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!